# What is Best? JavaCV(OpenCV) or FaceDetector in android?

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, javacv

I'm going to implement face recognition in my android application. Which one is best to use, JavaCV or FaceDetector? Please suggest one to me.

Comment: Best for what purpose? Application size, effectiveness at detecting faces, easiest to implement?

Comment: fast detecting and easy to implement.....

Answer (score 2):

FaceDetector may be using a C++ implementation which would be faster. I would suggest using FaceDetector for that reason as well as limiting your application size. Including the JavaCV Jar will increase application size which will make people less likely to download it and more likely to uninstall it to free up space on the phone.

If FaceDetector doesn't work as well as you want it to, use JavaCV. FaceDetector uses eyes only to detect faces so it will not detect profiles, or faces that do not have both eyes visible.

FaceDetector Note: [The width of the image must be even.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html#FaceDetector%28int,%20int,%20int%29)